# Unit testing filter error: Expected null to equal [object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm a little new to AngularJS and unit testing(Jasmine). I've been trying to run a filter test and I keep getting "Expected null to equal Volvo." I understand that the for some reason when I call filterInstance(cars,1), I'm always returned null - as in the car cannot be found. Could you please help me find my error?

filters.js:

```
var vmaFilterModule = angular.module('FilterModule', []);
vmaFilterModule.filter('getById', function() {
return function(input, id) {
var i=0, len=input.length;
for (; i<len; i++) {
  if (+input[i].id == +id) {
    return input[i];
  }
}
return null;
} 
});
```

filtertest.js

```
describe("Filter Test", function () {

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var filterInstance;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module("FilterModule"));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($filter) {
    filterInstance = $filter("getById");
}));

it("gets correct car", function () {
   expect(filterInstance(cars, 1)).toEqual("Volvo");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this...

note: There is no input[i].id use the var i;

```
var vmaFilterModule = angular.module('FilterModule', []);

vmaFilterModule.filter('getById', function() {
  return function(input, id) {
    var i=0, len=input.length;
    for (; i<len; i++) {
      if (i == +id) {
        return input[i];
      }
    }
   return null;
  } 
});
```

However, if **INPUT** is always an array, and **ID** is always passed as the second parameter, than you don't have to loop.

```
var vmaFilterModule = angular.module('FilterModule', []);

vmaFilterModule.filter('getById', function() {

  return function(input, id) {
    if( !input ){ return null; }
    return input[id] || null; // Like you did, use the + to force number if needed.
  });
```

**UPDATE 2**

If your data is this...

```
var cars = [ { content: "Scion", id: 4 }, { content: "Volvo", id: 2 }, { content: "Honda", id: 3 }, { content: "Toyota", id: 7 } ];
```

Then without changing **ANYTHING** in the filter, you can test like this...

```
it( "gets correct car", function(){
  expect( filterInstance(cars, 2).content ).toEqual( "Volvo" );
}); // notice the .content change.
```

Your filter is going to return an object like this

```
{ content: "Volvo", id: 2 }
```

This means you have to call the property with the value you seek to evaluate.

Comment: Since I'm not allowed to make changes to the filters.js function. Would I be able to somehow mock the array being called upon so I can reflect that change in filtertest.js?

Comment: The filter most likely does not work with an array, but an object with ID properties. Hold on.

Comment: What does the filter get? input is not an array or object.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your filter will not work in the way it is. You will either pass in an array and change as I mentioned, or use an object with id: props and maybe a value: prop and change your return to return input[i].value.

Comment: It's an array of objects. Here's what's being passed.


    var cars = 
    [
 {
        content: "Scion",
        id: 4
 },
 {
        content: "Volvo",
        id: 2
 },
 {
  content: "Honda",
        id: 3
 },
 {
  content: "Toyota",
        id: 7
    }
];

Comment: "here's what's being passed" where did you put it?

Comment: See my above changes UPDATE 2.